# Alter Datomic schema (unique -> not unique)

Tags: clojure, schema, datomic

Good day everyone,

I would like to see if it's possible to "alter" datomic schema - in particular make attribute value **not unique** after it was declared **unique** in first place.

Schema:

```
    {:db/id                 #db/id[:db.part/db]
     :db/ident              :vcs/reference
     :db/doc                "Our VCS reference number for a transaction"
     :db/valueType          :db.type/string
     :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one
     :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}

    {:db/id               :vcs/reference
     :db/unique           :db.unique/value
     :db.alter/_attribute :db.part/db}
```

The possibility of doing so doesn't sound right because:

- It's changing the history
- If applied other way around (not-unique -> unique) will create data
  conflicts.

Could anyone please clarify this?

**UPDATE**

Found [Datomic Schema-Alteration doc](http://docs.datomic.com/schema.html#Schema-Alteration) in case anyone else will be searching.

**UPDATE 2**

To solve my particular problem I've done the following:

```
 (d/transact-async conn [[:db/retract :vcs/reference :db/unique :db.unique/value]
                         [:db/add :db.part/db :db.alter/attribute :vcs/reference]])
```

In case you adding a uniqueness constraint - data will have to be manually updated to avoid the conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for posting the link - that is a newer doc page I'd not seen before.

Comment: Yeah, hopefully it will save someone else time too.

Answer (score 1):

A related point is that, unlike columns in a SQL table, attributes can never be "deleted".  All you can do is stop using them and "forget" that they ever existed.

If your db attributes need to evolve (and when don't they?), you may wish to version them just like the routes in an REST API. This is easily done by adding a component like ".v2" to the namespace:

```
:db/ident              :person.v1/age
:db/valueType          :db.type/string
```

could be replaced by:

```
:db/ident              :person.v2/age
:db/valueType          :db.type/long
```

and then:

```
:db/ident              :person.v3/age
:db/valueType          :db.type/double
```

Note that different groups of attributes may be versioned differently (like each table in a SQL db):

```
:db/ident              :vehicle.v42/horsepower
:db/valueType          :db.type/double
```

Of course, if your DB changes enough, it may eventually be worthwhile to copy the data (ETL) into a completely new DB with a different organization & structure.